# Can I use an image of SpongeBob in the thumbnail of my video about the cartoon?

Tags: united-states, copyright, fair-use, is-x-legal

Suppose I made a commentary video about SpongeBob. Would using an image of SpongeBob in the thumbnail be considered fair use in this case?

Comment: Keep in mind that the content policies of video platforms can be stricter than what the law says. Just because something doesn't break federal copyright law does not mean that a privately owned platform is obligated to host it. If a video platform says "We don't care about fair use; if you use an image copyrighted by one of our partners, we take your video down", then that's within their right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, as it seems to [meet the standards of](https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html#107):

- Relationship to the whole (small part of the animation)
- Effect on value of the copyrighted word (likely negligible effect)
- Purpose and character - commentary, uniquely identifying the subject of the commentary.

The outstanding portion to be considered, nature of the copyrighted work, as a work of fiction targeted at children, is not in your favor (you aren't trying to copy a phonebook, for example), but given the other factors, should not weigh heavily enough against you to cause problems.

That said, fair use might not be enough to protect against a copyright bot, so modifying the image to show context of this as a commentary would probably be beneficial in more than one way.